# Positive curvature of the boundary away from a point implies regularity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemannian-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

In a paper I'm refereeing, the authors make use of the following geometric fact:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If there is a point $p\in \partial U$ so that $\partial U \backslash p$ is a smooth curve with positive geodesic curvature with respect to the outward normal, then $\partial U$ is piecewise smooth and the angle between the left and right tangents to $\partial U$ at $p$ (inside of $U$) is positive.

I'm having some difficulty following the proof provided in the paper.  I've also played around a bit and haven't been able to come up with anything on my own.  Does anyone know if this has been treated in the literature or if there is an elementary proof?

Some Remarks:

1. The key fact to show is that the the left and right tangents to $\partial U$ exist at $p$.
2. The region $U$ does not need to be convex (e.g. if $U$ is a half-disk of radius 2 glued to two half-disks of radius 1).

Comment: The boundary is non-self-intersecting, this implies that the total curvature away from $p$ is bounded (in fact by $4\pi$). This implies that the left and right tangents exist. I am not sure what it means for the angle between them to be positive; can you explain that terminology?

Comment: In particular, I would expect that the region $U$ you described in item (2) of your post, and the region $U'$ obtained from something that looks like an ice cream cone, should have differently signed angles at $p$. So perhaps there are hidden assumptions that you did not tell us? (Positivity of angle also doesn't jive well with the example of the disk, where by most measures the angle should be zero.)

Comment: By angle I meant the angle between the left and right tangents to the boundary that pointed into the interior of the boundary.  So the example in 2) has angle $2\pi$ with respect to the interior and $0$ with respect to the exterior.  Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Also thanks for the suggestion to use the total curvature, that gives a nice clear proof.

Comment: Oh, in this case then by definition you are only ruling out an interior angle 0? Okay, this can also be done using total curvature, since the interior angle being 0 requires that the total curvature to be zero, which contradicts that the curvature is pointwise positive everywhere.